# Do Ruby errors get propagated up the call chain when they occur? Getting weird behavior

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, aws-sdk

I am writing some simple code in Ruby that uses a begin...rescue block to call a method and (hopefully) catch any errors caused by AWS and the aws-sdk for ruby. I won't get into a lot of details but for now I am trying to rescue a StandardError as a way to test easily. In my class I have

```
begin
  OtherFileClass.method_with_aws_call(variable)
rescue StandardError
```

and in the method, I am just raising a StandardError to make sure it gets caught in the calling class

```
raise StandardError
```

but when I call my method in the begin/rescue, the method doesn't propagate back to the rescue, it just ends execution and prints StandardError to the logs. Do I need to do more than raise an error in the called method? Do I need to rescue it and return? I'm a little confused on this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I am silly. I had two paths of execution, one that made a temp file with any AWS S3 files that failed to delete, and one that deleted those S3 files. Since I raised an error, it didn't delete the temp file when expected and thus caused this weird failure as it went down the path with no rescue... I will have to cover that edge case but for now this is solved.